# HLS streaming on JWPlayer 8 in IE11

Tags: jwplayer

Does anyone know if it's possible to get streaming on JWPlayer 8 to work with IE11 on Windows 7? The JWPlayer docs are a little unclear on it. And their own demo also doesn't work on IE11 / Win7.

Unfortunately our site has around 6% IE11 users so we still need to support it. We would like to upgrade to jwplayer 8 to get the accessibility benefits.

- JWPlayer demo: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/basic/audio-metadata/
- Stream is .m3u8 HLS
- JW8 Browser and device reference: https://support.jwplayer.com/articles/jw8-browser-and-device-reference (seems to indicate that IE11 / Win7 *is* supported.

Apologies that I can't share my development URL but that is not possible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that works using Flash, do you have the latest Flash plugin installed?